# Why is my table missing a line between columns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

Why is there a line missing between Healthy and total column?

```
\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|c|}

\hline

   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{BMI} \\ 

\multirow{-2.5}{*}{\makecell{Activity level}}& {Unhealthy} & {Healthy} &
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{\makecell{Total}} \\

\hline

Inactive  & 25 & 21 & 46\\ 

Active & 9 &  45 & 54\\ 

\hline

Total &34 & 56 & \textbf{100}\\

\hline

\end{tabular} 

\caption{\label{tab:table-name}Data on activity level, resting heart rate 
and BMI}

\label{conting2}

\end{center}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: you specified `|c|cc|c|`  so no line between columns 2 and 3

Comment: The code does not match the output you show.

Comment: @leandriis I have just copied and pasted it from latex and took a screenshot of the pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, I mean the column between healthy and total - I have edited the question

Comment: @Ng123: The table in your code has 4 columns, the screenshot shows 5. So it does not match?

Comment: @leandriis you count the multicolumn{2} as two columns

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{BMI} &\\ ` should add the missing lines.

Comment: @Ng123: The screenshot you show includes a column named "resting heart rate". This whole column is not present in the code you show.

Comment: the entries 16 and 8 are in your output but not the code, it is a different table.

Comment: @leandriis sorry both - I have amended the post again

Comment: you undid my code markup, select  the code and use the `{}`button to mark it as a code block. and the code *still* does not match the output

Answer (score 1):

Although the output doesn't match the picture, you could replace the header part by something like this, which gave a table with all lines for me:

```
 Activity level  &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{BMI} & Total\\ 
                 & {Unhealthy} & {Healthy} &      \\
```

edit: adjusted according to leandriis

Comment: This will give you a doubled line between "BMI"  and "Total". The `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` commands around "Activity level"  and "Total"  are redundant.

Comment: Thats right, sorry and thanks